# Javascript appendChild script that has php as source

Tags: javascript

I have an external javascript file that ends with .php

I need to load it dynamically, something like this:

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = url;
$("#someElement").append( script );
```

That does create the script tag, but the browser never makes the network request to load the script. When I manually put the script tag on the page, it loads.

Only problem is I need to load it conditionally based on client side javascript code.

Is eval() my only option here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was conditionally adding the code based on a media query. I removed the client side js media query, and used nginx detectmobilebrowser.com plugin.

Reason I was doing it client side was because of caching. Adding a mobile detection variable to the cache key simplified things greatly.

Answer (score 0):

you may not have jquery, or have it ready. try this instead

```
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Unless you need it at the specific element for some reason. But also, what's up with the JS file ending with .php? Maybe you can clarify that

Comment: also maybe share more of your code and make a JSFiddle, the more I read the question the more confused I'm getting...

Comment: it's a third party network that has the tag like <script type="text/javascript" src=".../include.php"> Adding that tag to the DOM did not make the network request.